# Numpy asarray() is saving PIL grayscale image as a green-ish image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision, python-imaging-library

I am trying to save a PIL image that is in grayscale as a Numpy array, but everytime I do so, the resulting image is not saved in grayscale, it is saved as a colorful, green-ish image. I am using this code to save the image:

```
from PIL import Image
import os
from numpy import asarray
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = Image.open('disparity_SGBM_norm.png')
npdata = asarray(image)
np.save("image", npdata)
plt.imshow(npdata)
plt.show()
```

So the original image is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Lp0g.jpg), but after using matplotlib to draw the resulting array, it reveals that it was saved as [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9fyL.jpg). Any idea why numpy is doing this, or is this because of matplotlib?

Comment: @Craig Yes, I am using `plt.imshow(npdata)` to plot the resulting array

Comment: @Craig Yes it does, thank you!